# VBA: Change the amount of minutes to hh:nn

Tags: excel, vba, time

For a VBA program, we have made two comboboxes. One for hours, one for minutes. We converted the hours into minutes. By a spinnerbutton, we can add or substract hours. We have converted them also into minutes. Now, we are seeking a way to convert the amount of minutes we have left into a messagebox with a hh:mm layout. 
Anybody who can help us out? Thanks in advance!

--CODE---

```
Private Sub CalcRT_Click()
UtcTime.Value = ((Hours.Value * 60) + Minutes.Value) + (TimeDifference.Value * 60) End Sub

Private Sub CalculateRT_Click()
    If UtcTime.Value >= 1440 Then
        UtcTime.Value = UtcTime.Value - 1440
    ElseIf UtcTime.Value <= 0 Then
        UtcTime.Value = UtcTime.Value + 1440
    End If
    Select Case UtcTime.Value
        Case 360 To 809
            i = 4
        Case 510 To 839
            i = 5
        Case 840 To 869
            i = 6
        Case 870 To 899
            i = 7
        Case 900 To 929
            i = 8
        Case 930 To 959
            i = 9
        Case 960 To 989
            i = 10
        Case 990 To 1009
            i = 11
        Case 1010 To 1439
            i = 12
        Case 0 To 299
            i = 12
        Case 300 To 314
            i = 13
        Case 315 To 329
            i = 14
        Case 330 To 344
            i = 15
        Case 345 To 359
            i = 16
    End Select
    MsgBox (Cells(i, 3) = Format(CalculateRT, "hh:nn"))
    '[something like this?] MsgBox ("is " & Format(Range("C4").Value, "HH:MM"))
End Sub
```

Comment: are you asking for example how to convert 123 to 2:03?

Comment: Please review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197413.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
dim i as long
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

MinutesElapsed = Format(Cells(i, 3) / 86400, "hh:mm")

MsgBox MinutesElapsed, vbInformation
```